# DropdownTextField in Flutter does not work with DarkTheme as expected

Tags: flutter, mobile, dropdown, darkmode

So, in my main application, I have this code which will make my app dark when the user is using dark mode and light otherwise:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'F1 Tracker',
      theme: ThemeData.light(),
      darkTheme: ThemeData.dark(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: DriversScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

But when using DropdownTextField in the following Stateless Widget in dark mode, both the background and the text colour are white, thus rendering the text invisible:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: DropDownTextField(
                controller: _constructorController,
                enableSearch: true,
                textFieldDecoration:
                    const InputDecoration(label: Text("Constructor")),
                validator: (String? value) {
                  if (value == null || value == "") {
                    return "Constructor cannot be empty!";
                  }
                  return null;
                },
                dropDownList: widget._constructorRepository
                    .findAllNames()
                    .map((e) => DropDownValueModel(name: e, value: e))
                    .toList(),
              ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

I pasted the whole code just to show I never set the background/text colour to white. This is how it looks in dark mode:
[image: Dropdown text invisible when using dark mode]

I've been trying to change the background colour/text colour, however with little success as all changes were applied only to the initial text field and not to the list as well. I'd appreciate some help with this, thanks.

Comment: Can you simplify the snippet that will contain only necessary part to reproduce the issue

Comment: I edited it so only the neccessary part is here

Comment: Are you using any package for `DropDownValueModel`?

Comment: Yes - I have it here: import 'package:dropdown_textfield/dropdown_textfield.dart';

Comment: There are few values are hard-coded on source code, not sure but it can cause this

Comment: How could I fix that?

Comment: Sorry, I dont know, I might skip this package